# PineScript: Unable to do Strategy Exit on partial Take profit and Stop Loss

Tags: pine-script

I believe this topic has been asked many times but after reading extensively and tried most of the work arounds, I am still at Square One.. Stuck with code and Issue remains. Let me explain the issue and request your kind help.

**PS:** I am not a techie so pl have larger paitence with me, thanks in advance.

**Objective:** I build a code which helps me enter trade when price crosses opening range but it should take book first profit (TP1) at fibbonacci 0.786 level is met and second one (TP2) when price crosses Fib 1.683 level. Simililarly when Price crosses opening range low, then Stop loss should trigger.

**Issue:** Code is initiating trade precicesly but it fails to trigger stop loss or TP1/TP2. Since my trigger conditions are boolean type, I guess I am not able to formulate the triggers. so your help will be appriciated.

**IMP**... as per code, plots are beng marked very correctly. so I guess issue is with defining the Exit on Sl and TP ... Conditions are found at the bottom of code

```
`
`
//// Entry and Exit conditions strats here ///
// Defind Buy and Sell Conditions
buy = ta.crossover( close, openingRangeHigh)
sell = ta.crossunder(close, openingRangeLow)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/// Pt1 and Pt2 are Profit target 1 and 2
/// Stoploss 1 and 2 are used for target 1 and target 2 respectively

pt1 = input.float(0.618, minval=0.0, maxval=15, title="Profit Target 1 - Multiple of Opening Range 0.618, .786, 1, 1.386, 1.618  etc.")
pt2 = input.float(1, minval=0.0, maxval=30, title="Profit Target 2 - Multiple of Opening Range 0.618, .786, 1, 1.386, 1.618 etc.")
sl1 = input.float(0.5, minval=0.0, maxval=15, title="Stop Loss 1 - Multiple of Opening Range 0.618, .786, 1, 1.386, 1.618  etc.")
sl2 = input.float(0.5, minval=0.0, maxval=15, title="Stop Loss 2 - Multiple of Opening Range 0.618, .786, 1, 1.386, 1.618  etc.")

//Formula For Profit Target 1
pft1 = pt1
highRes2 = openingRangeMid + ((openingRangeHigh-openingRangeLow)*pft1)
lowRes2 = openingRangeMid - ((openingRangeHigh-openingRangeLow)*pft1)

//Highlighting Line rules for Profit Target 1
highColor2 = high > highRes2 ? color.lime : color.lime
lowColor2 = low < lowRes2 ? color.lime : color.lime

//Formula For Profit Target 2
pft2 = pt2
highRes3 = openingRangeMid + ((openingRangeHigh-openingRangeLow)*pft2)
lowRes3 = openingRangeMid - ((openingRangeHigh-openingRangeLow)*pft2)

//Highlighting Line rules for Profit Target 2
highColor3 = high > highRes3 ? color.aqua : color.aqua
lowColor3 = low < lowRes3 ? color.aqua : color.aqua

//Rules for when to plot Numbers 1 or 2 When Profit Target 1 or 2 is Reached
pt1UHit = (high >= highRes2  and high[1] < highRes2 and high[2] < highRes2 and high[3] < highRes2 and high[4] < highRes2 and high[5] < highRes2) 
pt1LHit = (low <= lowRes2  and low[1] > lowRes2 and low[2] > lowRes2 and low[3] > lowRes2 and low[4] > lowRes2 and low[5] > lowRes2) and low > lowRes3
pt2UHit = (high >= highRes3  and high[1] < highRes3 and high[2] < highRes3 and high[3] < highRes3 and high[4] < highRes3 and high[5] < highRes3) 
pt2LHit = (low <= lowRes3  and low[1] > lowRes3 and low[2] > lowRes3 and low[3] > lowRes3 and low[4] > lowRes3 and low[5] > lowRes3)

//Rules for plotting 1 or 2 When Profit Target 1 or 2 is Reached
plotchar( pt1UHit ? pt1UHit : na, title='UpSide Profit Target 1 Achieved', char='TP1', location=location.abovebar, color=color.white)
plotchar( pt1LHit ? pt1LHit : na, title='DownSide Profit Target 1 Achieved', char='TP1', location=location.belowbar, color=color.white)
plotchar( pt2UHit ? pt2UHit : na, title='UpSide Profit Target 2 Achieved', char='TP2', location=location.abovebar, color=color.white)
plotchar( pt2LHit ? pt2LHit : na, title='DownSide Profit Target 2 Achieved', char='TP2', location=location.belowbar, color=color.white)

// Defind SL
slt1 = sl1
highRessl2 = openingRangeMid + ((openingRangeHigh-openingRangeLow)*slt1)
lowRessl2= openingRangeMid - ((openingRangeHigh-openingRangeLow)*slt1)
//Highlighting Line rules for Profit Target 1
highColorsl2 = low > highRessl2 ? color.lime : color.lime
lowColorsl2 = high < lowRessl2 ? color.lime : color.lime

//Formula For Profit Target 2
slt2 = sl2
highRessl3 = openingRangeMid + ((openingRangeHigh-openingRangeLow)*slt2)
lowRessl3 = openingRangeMid - ((openingRangeHigh-openingRangeLow)*slt2)
 
//Highlighting Line rules for Profit Target 2
highColorsl3 = low > highRessl3 ? color.aqua : color.aqua
lowColorsl3 = high < lowRessl3 ? color.aqua : color.aqua


//Rules for when to plot Numbers SL1 or SL2 When Profit SL 1 or 2 is Reached
sl1UHit = (low <= highRessl2  and low[1] > highRessl2 and low[2] > highRessl2 and low[3] > highRessl2 and low[4] > highRessl2 and low[5] > highRessl2) 
sl1LHit = (high >= lowRessl2  and high[1] < lowRessl2 and high[2] < lowRessl2 and high[3] < lowRessl2 and high[4] < lowRessl2 and high[5] < lowRessl2) and high < lowRessl3
sl2UHit = (low <= highRessl3  and low[1] > highRessl3 and low[2] > highRessl3 and low[3] > highRessl3 and low[4] > highRessl3 and low[5] > highRessl3) 
sl2LHit = (high >= lowRessl3  and high[1] < lowRessl3 and high[2] < lowRessl3 and high[3] < lowRessl3 and high[4] < lowRessl3 and high[5] <lowRessl3)

//Rules for plotting 1 or 2 When Profit Target 1 or 2 is Reached
plotchar( sl1UHit ? sl1UHit : na, title='UpSide StopLoss Target 1 Achieved', char='SL1', location=location.abovebar, color=color.white)
plotchar( sl1LHit ? sl1LHit : na, title='DownSide StopLoss Target 1 Achieved', char='SL1', location=location.belowbar, color=color.white)
plotchar( sl2UHit ? sl2UHit : na, title='UpSide StopLoss Target 2 Achieved', char='SL2', location=location.abovebar, color=color.white)
plotchar( sl2LHit ? sl2LHit : na, title='DownSide StopLoss Target 2 Achieved', char='SL2', location=location.belowbar, color=color.white)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Since 

Bars_countb = ta.barssince(sl1UHit)
Bars_countb:=nz(Bars_countb)
if Bars_countb<=0
    Bars_countb:=1
slBuyHigh = ta.lowest(Bars_countb)
plot(slBuyHigh)


Bars_counts = ta.barssince(sl1LHit)
Bars_counts:=nz(Bars_counts)
if Bars_counts<=0
    Bars_counts:=1
slSellHigh = ta.highest(Bars_counts)
plot(slSellHigh)

// // Defining Target

Bars_countsbt1 = ta.barssince(pt1UHit)
Bars_countsbt1:=nz(Bars_countsbt1)
if Bars_countsbt1<=0
    Bars_countsbt1:=1
tpBuyHigh1 = ta.highest(Bars_countsbt1)
plot(tpBuyHigh1)


Bars_countsbt2 = ta.barssince(pt2UHit)
Bars_countsbt2:=nz(Bars_countsbt2)
if Bars_countsbt2<=0
    Bars_countsbt2:=1
tpBuyHigh2 = ta.highest(Bars_countsbt2)
plot(tpBuyHigh2)


// // for Sell side targets use Fib "openingRangeFib_X_Low" values

Bars_countsst1 = ta.barssince(pt1LHit)
Bars_countsst1:=nz(Bars_countsst1)
if Bars_countsst1<=0
    Bars_countsst1:=1
tpSellHigh1 = ta.lowest(Bars_countsst1)
plot(tpSellHigh1)


Bars_countsst2 = ta.barssince(pt2LHit)
Bars_countsst2:=nz(Bars_countsst2)
if Bars_countsst2<=0
    Bars_countsst2:=1
tpSellHigh2 = ta.lowest(Bars_countsst2)
plot(tpSellHigh2)


// // PLOT =============================================================================================================
plotshape(buy, title='LONG SIGNAL', style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text = "Long Entry", size=size.small)
plotshape(sell, title='SHORT SIGNAL', style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text = "Short Entry", size=size.small)
 
plotshape(slBuy, title='SL-Buy SIGNAL', style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, text = "on SL", size=size.tiny)
plotshape(slSell, title='SL-Short SIGNAL', style=shape.xcross, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text = "on SL", size=size.tiny)

plotshape(tgtBuy1, title='TP1-Buy SIGNAL', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.rgb(247, 252, 0), text = "TP 1", size=size.tiny)
plotshape(tgtSell1, title='TP1-Short SIGNAL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(247, 252, 0), text = "TP1", size=size.tiny)

plotshape(tgtBuy2, title='TP1-Buy SIGNAL', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.rgb(252, 185, 0), text = "TP 2", size=size.tiny)
plotshape(tgtSell2, title='TP1-Short SIGNAL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(252, 185, 0), text = "TP 2", size=size.tiny)

**//// Problem starts here /////**

// Strategy Entry conditions

if (buy)  
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

    // strategy.exit("Long", from_entry="Long", limit= close, when = tpBuyHigh1, qty_percent=50, comment="Hit profit target 1 ")
    // strategy.exit("Long", from_entry="Long", limit= close, when = tpBuyHigh2, qty_percent=100, comment="Hit profit target 2 ")
    // strategy.exit("Long", from_entry="Enter Long", limit=slBuyHigh, comment="SL Hit ")

    strategy.close("Long", when=tpBuyHigh1, qty_percent = 50, comment = "close buy entry for 50%" )
    strategy.close("Long", when=tpBuyHigh2, qty_percent = 100, comment = "close buy entry for 100%" )
    strategy.close("Long", when = slBuyHigh, comment = "on SL") 

if (sell)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

    // strategy.exit("Short", from_entry="Short", limit= close, when = tpSellHigh1, qty_percent=50, comment="Hit profit target 1 ")
    // strategy.exit("Short", from_entry="Short", limit= close, when = tpSellHigh2, qty_percent=100, comment="Hit profit target 2 ")
    // strategy.exit("Short", from_entry="Enter Long", limit=slSellHigh, comment="SL Hit ")
    strategy.close("Short", when=tpSellHigh1, qty_percent = 50, comment = "close Sell entry for 50%" )
    strategy.close("Short", when=tpBuyHigh2, qty_percent = 100, comment = "close Sell entry for 100%" )
    strategy.close("Short", when = slSellHigh, comment = "on SL")

/// end of code ///
``
```